# ValueError: time data does not match format when parsing a date

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, format

When I try to parse a string to a datetime, I do this (having imported datetime before):

```
fecha_2 = datetime.strptime('22/01/2019 17:00', '%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
```

However, I receive this error

> ValueError: time data '22/01/2019 17:00' does not match format '%d/%m/%y %H:%M'

anyone know why?

Comment: lower case `'y'` means 2 digit year rather than 4 digit year

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `y` should be capitalized. This is referenced in the Python docs found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

This works fine

`fecha_2 = datetime.strptime('22/01/2019 17:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a capital `Y` for a 4 digit year (lowercase `y` is for a 2 digit year like `19`). So:

```
>>> fecha_2 = datetime.strptime('22/01/2019 17:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
>>> fecha_2
datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 22, 17, 0)
```

[strptime docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 2):

The above is correct. However, to avoid these kind of errors you can use dateutil.parser, which can automatically guess the correct format string. You can install it by doing pip install python-dateutil

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse("2018-06-19 11:21:13.311")
datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 19, 11, 21, 13, 311000)
```